# Why can I make, but not approve, edits?

Tags: discussion, support, review-queues, suggested-edits, edits

As a user with 2000+ reputation, I can edit questions and answers immediately, but I cannot approve or reject changes made by others: I can only vote for or against and wait for some consensus. This makes little sense, since if a pending edit is wrong or incomplete, I cannot fix it myself. I can only vote against it, and wait for enough other users to do so before being able to make my own immediate correction.

I feel like this changed some time in the last couple of years, as I thought I remembered being able to instantly approve or reject proposed edits.

Comment: You can always pick *Improve*; improved suggested edits include a veto approve or decline (depending on wether or not you checked the 'this edit was helpful' checkbox when editing). You could only ever insta-approve or reject suggested edits *on your own posts*.

Comment: Given the crappy reviews performed, even by higher rep users, thank goodness there is at least some sort of consensus required. You might be great ... others are not so much.

Comment: It's been a while since I used Improve (if ever); I thought I remembered it working as essentially hijacking the user's edit, which I don't always feel is necessary (they made the substantial correction or contribution, I just want to make a small correction to it). But, as with many things, I could be mistaken :)

Comment: Oh, I'm not very active on the meta sites: why the down votes? Lack of research?

Comment: If you improve an edit, the revision history shows the entire edit they made (with their name against it), followed by a second edit showing your improvement (with your name). So you don't hijack it as such.

Comment: The downvote on Meta means "I don't agree with this proposal". In my case, it's because I think the SE queue needs to be *more* rigorous.

Comment: I keep forgetting to hijack the process, and get stuck with an edit I *wanted* to make, but then a suggested one in the queue, and neither end up going through because they are waiting on others.  This system is BROKEN.

Comment: There seems to have been another change (or regression) to the logic at issue here -- or it was never fixed correctly in the first place. For the longest time, if there was an edit pending, and I clicked 'edit' I could immediately approve the edit - now, as described, you are stuck waiting on other approvals (which is nonsensical). Many times I DO NOT want to improve the edit, I merely want to see what has changed, and help out by either approving or rejecting the original edit without taking creative license. There is no reason that approving original edit should require further review.

Comment: Related: [Reviewer overboard! Or a request to improve the onboarding guidance for new reviewers in the suggested edits queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420349)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the "Improve Edit" button. This short-circuits the review and prevents others from automatically accepting bad edits.

[image]

The person suggesting the edit still gets the +2 to their reputation.

If you think the post needs improving but that the suggestion wasn't good enough then use the "Reject and Edit" button. This will replace their suggestion with your edit and they won't get the +2 reputation.

Comment: From my understanding, it only short circuits the review if you are quicker at improving the post than the reviewers behind you are at approving it. Which in practice I find is rarely the case

Comment: @OGHaza - but your edits should override the suggested edit once you submit them (admittedly it's a while since I've done this). Perhaps it would be nice if clicking "Improve" removed the edit from the review queue straight away - but that would be a separate feature request.

Comment: If the recommended action is to short-circuit the process, then the process is flawed.

Comment: @ErickRobertson - though you will have to make a substantial edit for this operation to go through.

Comment: There's always something extra that can be cleaned up.  Otherwise, couldn't I just add a dummy paragraph, and then immediately edit it again to remove the paragraph?

Comment: Fortunately, that was ameliorated several months after your comment here, @OGHaza. Reviewers [now have 3 minutes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/270498/603977) in which the queue will not assign the review to anyone else.

Comment: Let me just mention that this perhaps the most annoying "feature" of stack overflow: it makes me feel that the site still does not trust me, despite having +40k rep on the network.  Perhaps there should be a level of reputation after which the site should not embarrass someone by essentially telling them "I still don't trust that you will not automatically accept a bad edit".  The "Improve Edit" workaround is not intuitive.