# Can I please see the modifications of the edit that I approved?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, edits, suggested-edits

I stumbled upon a question with some unindented code. I hit **edit**, realising that it was actually **edit(1)** while the popup popped up.

There's an edit pending and....it does exactly what I was about to do myself, fix the code. Awesome! **Approve**.

But what's that? The edit needs more approvals?
Ok, I get it, I possibly am that other spam bot. That's good, the system prevents my inner spam bot to approve that possibly nonsense edit from my brother spam bot. Awesome!

But when I close the edit pop up, I'm left with the unedited question.
Not so awesome!

- I don't want to change the edit.
- [I don't want to game the system](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252983/4347580) and work around the review queue.
- I don't want to take away the opportunity of others to approve this edit.

But I still approved that edit. And I really want to see the modifications the edit made.

**Can I please see the modified, edited version of the content that I approved but which is still stuck in the approval queue?** Just like it does when suggesting an edit with sub 2k rep?

That would be awesome!

### No, it does not solve my problem

if we [had this same problem 3 freakin' years ago already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125909/why-dont-pending-edits-i-approve-show-for-me) and came to the same [upvoted and conclusively agreed upon solution](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/131417/show-the-edited-form-of-the-question-when-ive-approved-it), without implementing it.

Comment: Cross-site dupe: [Show the edited form of the question when I've approved it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/131417/288751)

Comment: Given it's a diamond suggesting that system-gaming, that's a reasonable workaround.