# Why are my edit approves not immediate?

Tags: discussion

Usually, I'm able to [edit questions without delay](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges) since I've over 2k reputation.

Earlier today, I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35128114/java-localized-date-with-short-date-pattern) and wanted to edit it so that the formatting is improved. I saw that [an edit was pending](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/11100752), checked it and approved it since it basically was what I wanted to do. So why aren't my approval of edits also immediate? (Especially since everybody before me approved the edit.)

If I had made the change myself, it'd be done immediately, but since it's someone else, me approving it isn't enough? I just don't understand this discrepancy.

From the "similar questions suggestions", I've seen lots of duplicates pointing to [a reference answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252983/180719) stating how to bypass this, but none explains why this clunky behavior exists at all.

Basically, since my word is enough for edits, when I click "approve" and ( this is important) no one rejected it before I approved it, my word should be enough without any extra steps. Why isn't this the case?

The keyword here is "*why*".

Comment: ... and weirdly despite people finding the duplicate very quickly, it wasn't present in my "similar questions suggestions" list.