# Why can I make edits but not approve edits?

Tags: discussion

I have earned the privilege to edit posts without needing those edits to be approved. Why does this not also grant me the privilege to approve edits suggested by others? It seems very stupid that I can't approve someone's edit, but I can copy it and paste it verbatim into my own edit.

I have seen this question: [Why can I make, but not approve, edits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252980/why-can-i-make-but-not-approve-edits). However, this is not a duplicate of that one. For one thing, the solution suggested there is a strange workaround for a bad behaviour. For another, I am not as interested in how to fix the problem (like I said I can just copy paste the edit into my own edit if I want to) as I am wondering **why** this design choice was made by Stack Overflow.

Just to be clear, I am not talking about review queues. I do not know if they work differently. I am talking about when I find a random question while browsing and I see that it has a pending edit. If I click on the edit and click on approve, it says "This suggestion still needs 1 approve vote from other reviewers. Close this popup (or hit Esc) to continue."

Comment: 3K should be enough to participate in review queues... Maybe you are banned for some reason (moderators would know)... http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit says you need just 2K to participate in reviews...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I'm not banned - I can participate in the queue.

Comment: Side note: after the edit it is clear that privilege you are looking for is the diamond level one ... No one else can single-handedly approve the edit (you should be able to take over as suggested in linked post so with "Improve"/"Reject and Edit" like everyone else without diamond)

Comment: Just encountered the same thing. It's unfortunate that this question was so poorly received (or misunderstood). I hope this gets changed.

Comment: @djv I agree - I'm not sure why this went down so badly. At the end of the day it's a totally inconsistent policy. I am trusted to make any edit, but I am not trusted to say that someone else's edit is ok.

Answer (score 5):

> If I click on the edit and click on approve, it says "This suggestion still needs 1 approve vote from other reviewers. Close this popup (or hit Esc) to continue."

Well, and what's wrong with that actually?

---

If you want to use your edit privilege powers to override that, choose the <kbd>Improve edit</kbd> or <kbd>Reject and edit</kbd> options instead.

Other choices will just queue you to the approval crew, which needs more users to agree.

---

As for the question *why it is implemented like this* currently, I think because it makes sense.

Actively editing makes a severe difference from reviewing edits for approval.

Comment: So you didn't answer the question at all. The question was why is the system designed that way. As I already said in my question, I am not interested in the workaround - I understand how to get around the system.

Comment: @nhouser9 That's not _getting around_ the system but just intended as is.  You can either choose participating in review, or choose your edit privilege to override everything. I don't get what's your point of bothering actually?

Comment: I fully agree with @nhouser9. The community trusts me to make **any** edit without further review. So you trust my assessment. But when I assess: "this edit by some other person is just fine"; then the community does not trust my assessment. And the editor has to wait for other reviewers for absolutely no good reason. The reason this is bad is because it is **inconsistent**!

Comment: @GhostCat I agree with you.  Often the edit someone else has made is to format unreadable code to make it readable. I "approve" their edit only to find I still won't get to see the improved question while trying to answer it until someone else also approves it.  Yes I could spend my own time making the same edit I wanted to approve, but it seems silly and also a bit high-handed, as if taking the credit for the original editor's work!

Comment: @TonyAndrews Well. It seems the "answer" is: to pay attention. Whenever I see such an edit in the queue for a question I am interested in, I go in and "improve" it. Maybe I am just updating one word; fixing a typo or changing "i ve" to "I have" or something alike. To then hit enter. The editor still gets his 2 points; and everybody else gets to see the improved question immediately.

Comment: @GhostCatsalutesMonicaC. That sounds more like the system is broken, and you are cheating to work around the broken system. (And I do think the system is broken.)